# Cannot install updates in Lubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Tags: package-management, updates, lubuntu

About 4-5 days ago, some updates showed up, but I had the router off. I - not knowing that - clicked on "Install". The update manager showed me "Downloading updates failed. Check your internet connection". So, I did not install the updates.

However, 2 days ago, with the router on, I clicked on "Install". It downloaded some packages, but others failed. And with those packages, the whole download process failed. I tried again a few times, also yesterday, but; the same result.

If you wonder, `apt` works perfectly - I can install, remove & purge packages normally.

Probably I have to reinstall `update-manager` because of corruption. But, if the issue is more complex, I am free to suggestions. I also want to install the new Linux kernel (`linux-4.4.0-111.134`) in order to avoid the Spectre and Meltdown vulnerabilities.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Insufficient data: Please edit your question to include the complete output of `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`. Please stick to one question per thread - the Spectre/Meltdown questions have been answered many times, so 'Search' is your friend.

Comment: @karel I reinstalled update-manager today and it worked perfectly! Thanks by the way for commenting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Reinstallation of Update Manager worked

I reinstalled `update-manager` today using `sudo apt install --reinstall update-manager` and it worked! It also installed some other updates that were available.